# Define a list of object values in ConfigParser

Tags: python, config

What would be the best way to define a config file and parse it using ConfigParser defining a bunch of objects initial values (aka: constructor values)

Example:

```
[Person-Objects]
Name: X
Age: 12
Profession: Student
Address: 555 Tortoise Drive

Name: Y
Age: 29
Profession: Programmer
Address: The moon
```

And then be able to parse it in Python so I can have something like:

```
People = []
for person in config:
    People.append(person)
Person1 = People[0]
print Person1.Profession     # Prints Student
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
[person:X]
Age: 12
Profession: Student
Address: 555 Tortoise Drive

[person:Y]
Age: 29
Profession: Programmer
Address: The moon
```

And then in your code:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('people.ini')
people = []

for s in config.sections():
    if not s.startswith('person:'):
         continue

    name = s[7:]
    person = dict(config.items(s))
    person['name'] = name

    people.append(person)
```